# SQL Server 2008R2 User Defined Function (Table valued) Performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, user-defined-functions

I am using SQL Server 2008R2.

I've got the following setup:

```
-- Query #1
SELECT * FROM
Product P
INNER JOIN ProductComments C ON C.ProductId = P.ProductId

-- Query #2
SELECT * FROM 
GetAllProducts() P
CROSS APPLY GetCommentsOfProduct(P.ProductId) C
```

where `GetAllProducts()` is

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetAllProducts
(      
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    SELECT * FROM Product
)
```

and `GetCommentsOfProduct(P.ProductId)` is

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetCommentsOfProduct]
(   
    @ProductId int
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    SELECT * FROM ProductComments WHERE ProductId = @ProductId
)
```

Both query #1 and query #2 result in the exact same actual execution plan and return the same result. Their query costs are both 50% relative to batch. Does this mean, that the SQL query optimizer translates these queries into the same query? And why is there no overhead for calling the UDFs? And does it mean I can structure all of my tables into UDFs and will have no performance issues even when doing JOIN operations? Do you know of any downsides?

Comment: Estimated or actual execution plan? You should be using `VIEW`s for this purpose instead...

Comment: "Do you know of any downsides" - never mind that, what are the upsides??

Comment: @AakashM This is not relevant for this question since I am just asking how SQL server technically behaves in this case.

Comment: **ACTUAL EXEC PLANS USE COST ESTIMATES**, not actual costs.  Please bear this in mind!!!

Comment: @JNK: Did you mean to say *‘ **Estimated** execution plans use cost estimates’*? If not, when/where then is it possible to see actual costs?

Comment: @AndriyM - Actual plans will show actual rowcounts and operators, but the cost amounts are still based on the estimates.  You can use `SET STATISTICS IO ON` to see actual page reads and whatnot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are [multiple ways](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx) to write a table-valued function.  The syntax you're using, with `AS RETURN`, is an "inline table-valued function".  This is equivalent to a view.  SQL Server will expand the function when executing the statement.  There is no overhead for calling this kind of function.

A "multi-statement table-valued function" is not equivalent to a view. The optimizer cannot ["inline"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_expansion) the multiple statements, so a "multi-statement TVL" often incurs significant overhead.

Answer (score 5):

> Does this mean, that the SQL query optimizer translates these queries
>   into the same query?

Yes. Inline table-valued functions are expanded into the outer query by the optimizer. Kind of like a macro.